# Decimal to Binary conversion 

Tags: c

I need to convert a 20digits decimal to binary using C programming. What buffer will I create, because it will be very large, even the calculator can't compute converting 20 digits to Binary.

here is sample of what i intend to accomplish:

Let is assume this code:
I am type this value via my keyboard into the buffer. Meanwhile, I am using an AT85C55WD Mcu.

unsigned char idata token[20]=(2,3,5,6,3,3,4,4,3,2,4,4,6,7,4,3,4,5,3,3);

I want a result

type-define variable convrt_token= 23562244324467434533;

Is this possible using C? If it is, then please how do i go about it?

Comment: yea, thank iMom0. but its how I will go about it!

Comment: If this is homework, add the **homework** tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is  elegent solution....:)

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define max 10000
#define RLC(num,pos) ((num << pos)|(num >> (32 - pos)))
#define RRC(num,pos) ((num >> pos)|(num << (32 - pos)))

void tobinstr(int value, int bitsCount, char* output)
{
    int i;
    output[bitsCount] = '\0';
    for (i = bitsCount - 1; i >= 0; --i, value >>= 1)
      {
             output[i] = (value & 1) + '0';
      }
}


  int main()
   {
    char s[50];
    tobinstr(65536,32, s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

each digit in decimal has 10 values, 0..9. so you'll need between 3 and 4 digits in binary. so let's say 4 to keep it simple.

so for a 20 digit decimal you'll need an 80 digit number in binary.

you can do it all with chars to keep it simple as well. i assume this is for fun.

char decnum[20];
char binnum[80];

good luck.

Comment: I am editing the question with a sample code of what I intend to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks Gidon,  but I am not intending to convert each digits to binary one after the other.

Comment: converting the entire 20digits to binary will give a 66bits.

Comment: the way to convert a whole big number to binary is one digit at a time. here's some pseudo code: for each digit in decnum do convert the digit to binary digits and concat them to binnum.

Answer (score 1):

Start off as Gidon mentions. Then you only need to define a function 'decToBin' or something like that, which you can use like this:

```
char decnum[20];  
char binnum[80];  

// ... get the values, do zero initialization etc...  
decToBin( decnum, binnum );
```

And you're ready to go.
The decToBin function could easily be implemented as a common long division algorithm. That shouldn't be too hard.
Have fun ;)

EDIT: Detailed description:

1. Look at your last digit. Is it divisible by 2?
   --> yes: your binary digit will be 0
   --> no: your binary digit will be 1
2. Divide the entire decimal number by 2 (Long division preferrably) and **truncate** if necessary.
3. start over. You will get the binary digits in reverse order. (Repeat until your decimal number is 0)

Comment: Thanks iolo, but I am not converting each bits to binary. I want to convert the entire 20 digits, which will give a 66bits binary.

Comment: That's why you will want to you use the long division algorithm you learned in fourth grade at school ;). Start with the leftmost digit, calculate quotient and remainder, move on to the next digit etc. It won't necessarily yield 66 bits by the way.