# Decimal to Binary conversion - I need Help

Tags: c, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decimal to Binary conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425696/decimal-to-binary-conversion)

I need to convert a 20digits decimal to binary using C programming. How do I go about it. Really, I am finding it hard. What buffer will I create, because it will be very large, even the calculator can't compute converting 20 digits to Binary.

I need suggestions, links and possibly sample codes.

Thanks.

Comment: This should be migrated to Stack Overflow, but it's too vague. You'll need to include the relevant code you already have. If you don't have any then you should do more research. Start with shorter numbers.

Comment: Are we talking integer or floating point representations? An integer twenty digit decimal numer would take between sixty-three and sixty-six bits to represent. Hardly "very large".

Comment: did you ask this question on two different stack exchange sites at the same time?

Comment: oh! I just observed this now.....its a mistake I i believe.!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to convert a decimal string to a binary string or to a value?

Rule of thumb 10^3 ~= 2^10, therefore 10^20 ~= 2^70 > 64 bits (67 to be accurate).

==> A 64bit integer will not not be enough. You can you a structure with 2 64bit integers (long long in C) or even a 8bit byte for the upper part and 64 for the lower part.
Make sure the lower part is unsigned.

You will need to write code that checks for overflow on lower part and increases upper part when this happens. You will also need to use the long division algorithm once you cross the 64bit line.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a library for extended precision arithmetic? try to give a look at http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are trying to convert a string of numerical characters into a really big int, or a really big int into a string of 1s and 0s... but in general, you'll be doing something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < digits; i++)
{
    bit[i] = (big_number>>i) & 1;
    // or, for the other way around
    // big_number |= (bit[i] << i);
}
```

the main problem is that there is no builtin type that can store "big_number". So you'll probably be doing it more like this...

```
uint8_t big_number[10]; // the big number is stored in 10 bytes.
// (uint8_t is just "unsigned char")
for (block = 0; block < 10; block++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        bit[block*8 + i] = (big_number[block]>>i) & 1;
    }
}
```

[edit]

To read an string of numerical characters into an int (without using `scanf`, or `atoi`, etc), I would do something like this:

```
// Supposing I have something like char token[]="23563344324467434533";
int n = strlen(token); // number of digits.
big_number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    big_number += (token[i] - '0') * pow(10, n-i-1);
}
```

That will work for reading the number, but again, the problem with this is that there is no built-in type to store big_number. You could use a float or a double, and that would get the magnitude of the number correct, but the last few decimal places would be rounded off. If you need perfect precision, you will have to use an *arbitrary-precision integer*. A google search turns up a few possible libraries to use for that; but I don't have much personal experience with those libraries, so I won't make a recommendation.

Really though, the data type you use depends on what you want to do with the data afterwards. Maybe you need an arbitrary-precision integer, or maybe a `double` would be exactly what you need; or maybe you can write your own basic data type using the technique I outlined with the blocks of `uint8_t`, or maybe you're better off just leaving it as a string!

Comment: Thanks Karadoc, I will actually want to convert the string of numeric character to a really bit int. And like you said there is no datatype to store the "big int". Here is the intention below ==>> unsigned char idata token[20]=(2,3,5,6,3,3,4,4,3,2,4,4,6,7,4,3,4,5,3,3);

I want a result===>>>

type-define variable convrt_token= 23562244324467434533;

Is this possible using C? If it is, then please how do i go about it?